# Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': unindent does not match any outer indentation level (lambda_function.py, line 26)

Tags: python, aws-lambda

Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': unindent does not match any outer indentation level (lambda_function.py, line 26)

```
from _future_ import print_function
import json
import boto3  
import time
import urllib

print('loading function')
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])
    try:
        print("Using waiter to waiting for object to persist thru s3 service")
        waiter = s3.get_waiter('object_exists')
        waiter.wait(Bucket+bucket, Key=key)
        response = s3.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        print("CONTENT TYPE: " +response['ContentType'])
        print("Etag: " + response['ETag'])
        print("Content-Length: ", response['ContentLength'])
        print("Keyname: "+key)
        print("Deleting object" + key)
        s3.delete_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        return response['ContentType']
    except Exception as e
         print(e)
         print('Error getting object{} from bucket {} . Make sure they exist'
         'bucket is in same region as this is'
         'function.' ,format(key, bucket))
         raise e
```

Comment: What's the question? The error message you pasted tells you exactly what's wrong. If you look at your line 26 (the `except` line), it clearly doesn't line up with the `try`, or with anything else. If you don't get why that's a problem, you need to read a basic Python tutorial.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Right here:

```
           print("Content-Length: ", response['ContentLength'])
           print("Keyname: "+key)
           print("Deleting object" + key)
           s3.delete_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
           return response['ContentType']
        except Exception as e: #<---also add me, the colon :)
            print(e)
            print('Error getting object{} from bucket {} . Make sure they exist'
            'bucket is in same region as this is'
            'function.' ,format(key, bucket))
            raise e
```

The indent of the stuff after the except needs to be moved back one space.

Comment: It's the indentation of the `except` line that needs to be fixed. The stuff following it isn't actually a problem.

Comment: True; a new indentation after a colon does not need to match previous indentation at the same depth. (But it's good for readability if it does.)

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is incorrect, **just like the exception says.**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
   # indented by 3 spaces
   try:
       ...
    # indented by 4 spaces ... 
    except Exception as e  # NOTE: Missing `:`
        ...
```

Your code example is **also missing a `:` at the end of the exception handler**

Comment: Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "'records'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      12,
      "lambda_handler",
      "bucket = event['records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']"
    ]
  ]
}


START RequestId: da868a03-37d2-11e8-9da6-2bbd6253bde7 Version: $LATEST
'records': KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 12, in lambda_handler
    bucket = event['records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
KeyError: 'records'

END RequestId: da868a0

Comment: I think it's best if you post a new question with this problem, since the one asked here originally has been solved.